# Can't append items to array with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, instagram

I'm trying to append the link value of Instagram images into an array. The link values are showing up fine in the console but my array length is 0 after the ajax function. Also '0' shows up in the console before all the links.

I have an idea this problem is caused by ajax running asynchronously and so the rest of the js code is actually run before anything can be appended to $images, but I have no idea how to circumvent this.  This is my code:

```
$liked = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked?access_token=' + $access_token + '&COUNT=20';
$images = []

$.ajax({
    type:'get',
    dataType:'jsonp',
    cache: false,
    url: $liked,
    success: function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
            console.log(data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url);
            $images.push(data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url);
        }

    }
});
console.log($images.length);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console.log will run before the ajax call is ended; write your code or you console.log in your success function right after the end of the data loop.

Like:

```
$liked = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked?access_token=' + $access_token + '&COUNT=20';
$images = []

$.ajax({
    type:'get',
    dataType:'jsonp',
    cache: false,
    url: $liked,
    success: function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
            console.log(data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url);
            $images.push(data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url);
        }
        console.log($images.length); // here the array is filled with response data
    }
});
```

Comment: But why would `$images` be of length 0 after the ajax call? Wouldn't the data stay there after being pushed into the array?

Comment: Okay, so now I'm getting the correct array length added. So does this mean that all my functions that use this filled array need to be called from within the success block?

Comment: Normally yes, but it depends on your needs and on your implementation

Comment: @jmazz If you want have your code isolated (functions/object not dependent on each other too much) you can raise an event inside the `success` function and have all the subscribers notified about new data. Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ or https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox